# Get all posts of all the users followed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A user has many posts and has many followees through follows sent.  How can I select all of the posts of all the users that a certain user is following?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :pwd_hash, :token, :username, :password, :avatar

  has_many(
    :follows_recieved,
    class_name: 'Follow',
    foreign_key: :followee_id,
    primary_key: :id
  )

  has_many :followers, through: :follows_recieved, source: :follower

  has_many(
    :follows_sent,
    class_name: 'Follow',
    foreign_key: :follower_id,
    primary_key: :id
  )

  has_many :followees, through: :follows_sent, source: :followee

  has_many(
    :posts,
    class_name: "Post",
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id
  )
```

UPDATE

Thanks to screenmutt for putting me on the right track.

I could not use find_all_by_relation but I could use find_all_by_field

so I just mapped the followee ids

```
ids = Follow.find_all_by_follower_id(current_user.id).map{ |f| f.followee_id }
posts = Post.find_all_by_user_id(ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this should work. You can always abstract it into a method.

```
Post.find_all_by_user(@current_user.followees)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write

```
has_many :posts
```

instead